# How to use DefinitetlyTyped definitions in Express app

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

How do i add Types from the Express definition to a function?

I have a function that takes an Express Request, and an Express Response as arguments, but i cannot get the type set correctly.

My standard JS function looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="../node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../express.d.ts" />

function postNewGame(req, res) {

}
```

But i'd like to enhance it with types from the Express Definition. Which should look something like this:

```
/// <reference path="../node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../express.d.ts" />

function postNewGame(req: Request, res: Response) {

}
```

But i what is the correct namespace or syntax to get the types to work?

The above sample gives this error `Could not find symbol 'Request'`

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

**Update 1**:

I should note that the file where i'm trying to do this, is not the app.js where i import the express module. My function resides inside a `my-routes` module that i `require` ins my app.js, and that might be my problem.

**Update 2**:

I made a simpler sample app to test this, and i'm still getting `Could not find symbol 'Request'` in my ***games.ts*** file.

My project structure is like this:

- .ts-definitions

  - express.d.ts
  - node.d.ts
- routes

  - games.ts
- app.ts

My ***app.ts*** looks like this (super simplified):

```
/// <reference path=".ts-definitions/express.d.ts" />
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

require('./routes/games')(app);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

and my ***games.ts*** like this:

```
/// <reference path="../.ts-definitions/express.d.ts" />

// How do i access express.Request, when express is not defined in the file?

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get('/games', function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) { // express is not defined
    res.render('games');
  });
}
```

To me it seems like the definitions only work in the file where i have `import express = require('express')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `import express = require('express');` even in files where you only use the interface/types. When you compile the file, if you don't actually use express, the TypeScript compiler is smart enough to leave it out of the compiled code.

```
/// <reference path="../.ts-definitions/express.d.ts" />

import express = require('express');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get('/games', function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    res.render('games');
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out a sample Express app written in pure TypeScript I wrote, you should be able to get the gist of how to manage your files there: https://github.com/czechboy0/Express-4x-Typescript-Sample

(Also, use [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/) instead of manually adding your typings headers, will save you lots of time.)